# spring-data-neo4j: @Query with depth

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am using `spring-data-neo4j` `v4.2.8`.
I have a `NodeEntity` with 2 `EntityRelationship` one is for incoming the other is for outgoing.

I want to load the nodes with a specific filter using the repository @Query method. **All relationship should be loaded with the node**. This is my query

```
@Query(value = "MATCH (n:`Person`) WHERE {0} IN labels(n) RETURN n")
Iterable<Person> findAllByLabels(String label);
```

=> I am loading nodes with two labels `Person` and a specific label.

I have tried many things:

1. using @depth in the method
2. specifying the relationship in the query like this.

   ```
   @Query(value = "MATCH (n:`Person`)<-[r]-() WHERE {0} IN labels(n) RETURN n")
   Iterable<Person> findAllByLabels(String label);
   ```

   In this case only the nodes with relationship are loaded and there is other problems with it.

What alternative do I have to make this work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I have found so far

```
@Query(value = "MATCH (n:`Person`) WHERE {0} IN labels(n) MATCH (n1:`Person`)<-[r1]-(n2:`Person`) WHERE {0} IN labels(n1) RETURN n,n1,n2,r1")
```

Answer (score 0):

With below, you can return every node even if it have no relationship.

```
@Query(value = "MATCH (n:`Person`) WHERE {0} IN labels(n)"
      + " OPTIONAL MATCH path=(n:`Person`)<-[r]-()"
      + " RETURN CASE path WHEN null THEN n ELSE path END")
  Iterable<Person> findAllByLabels(String label);
```

> Only the relationship available in `Person` class will be mapped.